# Как заблокировать манипуляцию с элементами окна, при Visibility=Visible?

Tags: wpf

Уважаемые программисты, прошу вашей помощи. Имеется приложение, выполненное в определённом едином стиле. Имеется кнопка, типа About (или "о авторе"..). Было бы winform приложение, не стал бы заморачиваться, а просто показал MessageBox, но как уже сказал, в моём приложении, такой MessageBox не подходит по стилю. А потому, я создал Grid полупрозрачный, на котором лежит Border+StackPanel+компоненты. У этого grid'a изначально Visibility=collapsed. Ну и соответственно, при нажатии на кнопку у этого грида Visibility ставится в Visible. Выглядит здорово. Но обнаружил неприятную штуку: когда показывается это окно, пользователь может Tab'om перейти с этой панели на другую, и соответственно делать там что душе угодно. Как бы мне запретить такие манипуляции юзера?  Вот часть xaml разметки:
Скрин:
    [image]

```
    <ListView x:Name="helpersListView" Grid.Row="2" MouseDoubleClick="helpersListView_MouseDoubleClick">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Заголовок" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding headerHelp}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Текст подсказки" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding helpText}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Тип" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding helpType.name_TypeHelp}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Дата добавления" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding dateAdd}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

<!--Вот эта панель, показывается после щелчка на опр. кнопке-->
    <Grid x:Name="aboutAuthorPanel" Grid.RowSpan="3" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
        <Border Background="Aqua" CornerRadius="10" Height="60" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Автор программы: </TextBlock>
                <Button Width="50" x:Name="okAuthorPanelButton" Click="okAuthorPanelButton_Click_1">Ок</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>                
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Это под WindowsPhone?

Comment: нет, это не phone. Обычное windows-приложение

Comment: в wpf нет модальных окон, так что да, можно переключится табом и работать с другом окне. сделайте его winform

Answer (score 2):

Это не совсем верно.
Вернее, можно конечно и рубить клавиатуру, но вдруг в форме окажется нечто большее, чем одна кнопка "Ok"?
Нужно создать в проекте новое окно (назовем его **AuthorWindow**)

```
<Window x:Class="AuthorWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="150" Height="80" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" 
        ShowInTaskbar="False" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        WindowStyle="None" 
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        Background="Transparent" >
    <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="AliceBlue">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="Автор программы:" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Василий Пупкин" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button Content="Ok" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_1" Background="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Это окно будет выглядеть примерно также, как ваше.
В обработчике **`Button_Click_1`**:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Тогда из родительской формы вам останется только вызвать его:

```
var form = new AuthorWindow();
form.ShowDialog();
```

Используем ShowDialog() вместо Show() как раз для того, чтобы родительская форма не реагировала ни на что, пока не закроется дочерняя. Аналог ModalForm для WinForms.

Как затемнить родительскую форму вы уже знаете.

Profit :)

Comment: да, просто мне не хотелось создавать для этого отдельную форму) но наверно, всё же ваш вариант более правильный

Answer (score 0):

Cделал вот так, не знаю насколько оно правильно:

```
private void Grid_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (aboutAuthorPanel.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Пользователь "Чебурашка" почти угадал.

В программе, **на окно** ставите обработчик события `PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown"`. В самом коде делаете так:

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Здесь проверяется, что нажатая кнопка это Tab
    if(e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Tab &&
    // Здесь проверяется, что ваше окно при этом видно
        aboutAuthorPanel.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible) 
    {
        // Это свойство сигнализирует о том, что дальше обрабатывать нажатие этой клавиши не нужно.
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

В результате нажатие кнопки Tab в таком окне обрабатываться не будет.